# Qt disabling dynamic buttons

Tags: c++, arrays, qt, dynamic, qpushbutton

I am trying to disable button previously chosen by user

```
void pracownik2::on_pushButton_4_clicked(){

this->setWindowTitle("EKRAN");
QWidget *centralWidget = new QWidget;
        int licznik=1;
        QString licz;
        //QString kolumny = ui->lineEdit->text();
        //QString wiersze = ui->lineEdit_2->text();
        miejsca2 = ui->lineEdit_3->text().toInt();
        //QPushButton *button[wiersze.toInt()][kolumny.toInt()];
        QPushButton *button[3][6];

        QGridLayout *controlsLayout = new QGridLayout;
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<6;j++)
            {
                    licz = QString::number(licznik);
                    licznik++;
                    button[i][j] = new QPushButton(licz);
                    button[i][j]->setCheckable(1);
                        if(tab[i][j]==1)
                            button[i][j]->setEnabled(false);
                    controlsLayout->addWidget(button[i][j], i, j);
            }
        }

        QPushButton *okej = new QPushButton("Zatwierdź");
        QPushButton *anul = new QPushButton("Anuluj");

        controlsLayout->addWidget(okej, 3, 0);
        controlsLayout->addWidget(anul, 3, 1);

        controlsLayout->setHorizontalSpacing(0);
        controlsLayout->setVerticalSpacing(0);
        centralWidget->setLayout(controlsLayout);

        setCentralWidget(centralWidget);



        for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<6;j++)
            {
                    connect(button[i][j],SIGNAL(toggled(bool)),this,SLOT(tescik(bool)));
            }
        }



        connect(anul,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(close()));

        connect(okej,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(okay2()));}

void pracownik2::tescik(bool t){
    if (t)
{
    tab[i][j]=1;
    miejsca++;
}
else
{
    tab[i][j]=0;
    miejsca--;
}}
```

but my 'tescik' function doesn't know what 'i' and 'j' are and the project won't compile, my question is how to make checked button set value 1 in the array and unchecked restore it to 0. I guess I have to edit 'connect' line but I have no idea how

@EDIT
I am trying to make this line

```
connect(button[i][j],SIGNAL(toggled(bool)),this,SLOT(tescik(bool,int i,int j)));
```

pass 'i' and 'j' of current button to function but it doesn't work

Comment: `connect(button[i][j], SIGNAL(toggled(bool)), button[i][j], SLOT(setDisabled(bool)));` additionaly

Comment: could you write something more about it cause I don't get it

Comment: If it's going to be disabled after being pressed, then how do you want to restore value in the array to 0?

Comment: @CentusDBWA does your previous call: connect(button[i][j],SIGNAL(toggled(bool)),this,SLOT(tescik(bool)));
            } work?

Comment: because changing array values isn't doing anything instantly, when the buttons are being shown second time, some of them are not enabled
@AB_ yes it works

Comment: @CentusDBWA to disable toggled button you can connect its `toggled()` signal with `setDisabled()` slot additionaly to connecting it with `tescik()` function..

Comment: What error do you receive  when it "doesn't work"? Please paste what compiler and meta compiler say.

Comment: No such slot pracownik2::tescik(bool,i,j) in ..\testpobi\pracownik2.cpp:83
line 83 is connect(button[i][j],SIGNAL(toggled(bool)),this,SLOT(tescik(bool,i,j)));
I tried making it (bool,int,int) etc and still it doesn't work

Comment: be sure to run qmake, you must always run it after changes have been made to signal/slots

Comment: Is it going to change state after user presses "OK"? If so, why don't you just check button states in the loop. You could do this inside `okay2()` slot.

Comment: @CentusDBWA did you run qmake?

Comment: Yes I did, the problem is I can't pass the arguements properly

Comment: You can not do `connect(button[i][j],SIGNAL(toggled(bool)),this,SLOT(tescik(bool,int i,int j)));`. Signal and slot signature must be compatible with each other. `QPushButton` would need to provide signal `toggled(bool, int, int)` to establish connection. Either extend `QPushButton` or check state of the buttons inside a loop as I said earlier.

Answer (score 0):

You can't connect

```
connect(button[i][j],SIGNAL(toggled(bool)),this,SLOT(tescik(bool,int i,int j)));
```

because how would `toggled` know what values of `i,j` pass to `tescik`?

You can however write a wrapper over QPushButtons so you can connect their `toggled(bool)` signals to single slot `toggled( int, int)` of this wrapper using [QSignalMapper](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsignalmapper.html). Then you can manage all this logic in such wrapper:

```
class ButtonHelperEntry
{
public:
    int i_;
    int j_;
    QPushButton* button_;
}

void ButtonHelper::initialize( const std::vector<
                                   QSharedPointer<ButtonHelperEntry> >& entries)
{
    entries_ = entries;
    mapper_.reset(new QSignalMapper(this));
    EntriesIterator it = entries_.begin();

    while ( it!=entries_.end())
    {
       connect(( *it)->button_, SIGNAL( toggled(bool)), mapper_.data(), 
                                                                   SLOT(map()));
       mapper_->setMapping( ( *it)->button_, (int)( *it)->i_, (int)( *it)->j_);
       it++;
       i++;
    }
    connect( mapper_.data(), SIGNAL( mapped(int,int)), 
                             this, SIGNAL( toggled(int,int)));
    connect( this, SIGNAL( toggled(int)), this, SLOT( updateValue(int)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would set i and j as properties of each button:

```
...
button[i][j]->setProperty("i", i);
button[i][j]->setProperty("j", j);
...
```

Then in tescik() get the sender and load i and j:

```
void pracownik2::tescik(bool t) {
   QObject * pSender = sender();
   int i = pSender->property("i").toInt();
   int j = pSender->property("j").toInt();

   if (t) {
   ...
```