# Qt connect statement

Tags: c++, qt, signals, connect, slot

I want to enhance my code which works but I fail to do so and my problem is how to pass arguments properly, I mean:

```
void pracownik2::on_pushButton_4_clicked(){

this->setWindowTitle("EKRAN");
QWidget *centralWidget = new QWidget;
        int licznik=1;
        QString licz;
        //QString kolumny = ui->lineEdit->text();
        //QString wiersze = ui->lineEdit_2->text();
        miejsca2 = ui->lineEdit_3->text().toInt();
        //QPushButton *button[wiersze.toInt()][kolumny.toInt()];
        QPushButton *button[3][6];

        QGridLayout *controlsLayout = new QGridLayout;
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<6;j++)
            {
                    licz = QString::number(licznik);
                    licznik++;
                    button[i][j] = new QPushButton(licz);
                    button[i][j]->setCheckable(1);
                        if(tab[i][j]==1)
                            button[i][j]->setEnabled(false);
                    controlsLayout->addWidget(button[i][j], i, j);
            }
        }

        QPushButton *okej = new QPushButton("Zatwierdź");
        QPushButton *anul = new QPushButton("Anuluj");

        controlsLayout->addWidget(okej, 3, 0);
        controlsLayout->addWidget(anul, 3, 1);

        controlsLayout->setHorizontalSpacing(0);
        controlsLayout->setVerticalSpacing(0);
        centralWidget->setLayout(controlsLayout);

        setCentralWidget(centralWidget);



        for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<6;j++)
            {
                    connect(button[i][j],SIGNAL(toggled(bool)),this,SLOT(tescik(bool)));
            }
        }



        connect(anul,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(close()));

        connect(okej,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(okay2()));}

void pracownik2::tescik(bool t){
if (t)
{
    miejsca++;
}
else
{
    miejsca--;
}}
```

This is working so far and I want 'tescik' function also to set values of my array:

```
void pracownik2::tescik(bool t, int i, int j){
if (t)
{tab[i][j]=1;
    miejsca++;
}
else
{tab[i][j]=0;
    miejsca--;
}}
```

I can't pass 'i' and 'j' indexes of current qpushbutton and I have no idea how to edit my connect line

```
connect(button[i][j],SIGNAL(toggled(bool)),this,SLOT(tescik(bool,int,int)));
```

it still has no idea what do I mean by int,int and I still have no idea how to make it work :)

Comment: You can't connect SIGNALs and SLOTs with different signatures. You could extend `QPushButton` and provide own signal if you really want to do this in this way.

Comment: Please don't post your question again, just modify previous one. Dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28125466/qt-disabling-dynamic-buttons

Comment: @doc, In fact you can. For example you can do something like this: `connect(sender, SIGNAL(signalWithThreeArgs(bool, int, int)), reciever, SLOT(slotWIthOneArg(bool)))`

Comment: @MikhailZimka Ah, true. I forget about it. So, signal must provide at least as much arguments as slot and their types must match.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is because of arguments mismatch when trying to connect signal and slot (signal is emitted with only one `bool`value, when slot takes three) - you should recieve corresponding message in your's application output. One of the solutions is to use QObject-dynamic properties. You can do something like this when creating your buttons:

```
button[i][j] = new QPushButton(licz);  
button[i][j]->setProperty("i", i);  
button[i][j]->setProperty("j", j);
```

And after that you can rewrite your slot:

```
void pracownik2::tescik(bool t) {
int i = QObject::sender()->property("i").toInt();  
int j = QObject::sender()->property("j").toInt();
if (t)  
{tab[i][j]=1;  
    miejsca++;  
}  
else  
{tab[i][j]=0;  
    miejsca--;  
}}
```